# How to show the time like this ex: 1sec ago , 1 min ago , 1 hour ago , 1 month ago

Tags: javascript

Hi i am very new Javascript, Can please any one help me regarding this?

I am getting from server date is : `2015-01-16T05:55:32.000Z`

I need to compare the current date and show like below

```
1 sec ago

2 min ago

2 hours ago

2 weeks ago

2 days ago

2 months ago

2 years ago
```

Using javascript and angular js

Can you please help me any one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use this format, consider also providing a way to see the exact time, perhaps in a tooltip or detail view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an excellent JavaScript library called Moment js where you can do such things: http://momentjs.com/

`moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();`

returns things like x seconds or days ago. It can parse the string you get from your server and it also provides translations for additional languages.

Regarding your example string:

```
var readable_date = moment('2015-01-16T05:55:32.000Z').fromNow();
```

This returns a readable answer as you can see in this fiddle

```js
var date = '2015-01-16T05:55:32.000Z';

var readable_date = moment(date).fromNow();

document.getElementById("date").innerText = readable_date;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.js"></script>

<span id="date"></span>
```

Comment: Hi @pfried, It is possible for this format : 2015-01-16T05:55:32.000Z

Comment: Hi Siva, yes it is possible, i will edit my answer to show you how